# Deformated mesh after exporting model from Blender to Substance Painter

Tags: export

I am trying to learn substance painter with blender. Until today i have not got problem.
Today i was working on my model of heater and i was trying to export it from blender to substance painter. Problem is in Substance painter when i have deformated mesh and i do not know what to do.
I was trying find solution at google for it but i did not find it.

Mesh faceing is fine.
Transforms are reseted.

I tried OBJ and FBX exporitng same result.

BLENDER : https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIFu8.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Eco.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofctF.jpg

SUBSTANCE PAINTER : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqrgl.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DzeV.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9R9j.jpg

Thanks for answears !!

Comment: what happens when you import the model into blender does it come up with the same issue? also have all modifiers been applied

Comment: When exporting to OBJ format, use the triangulate option.

Comment: Thanks - Lemon

When i exported my model via triangulate option everythink is fine!( without deformeted meshes)